# Sum of digits program not giving correct o/p for bigger numbers

Tags: c, scanf

I have written a program to find the sum of digits. When I use *big* numbers say a 10 digit number then I am getting some incorrect answer.

For example, if I give the input as `9999999999` then the output is `46`. Below is my code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sum,value,rem;
    printf("Enter the value:");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    sum= 0;
    while((value/10)>0)
    {
        rem=value%10;
        sum=sum+rem;
        value=value/10;
    }
    sum=sum+value;
    printf("Sum of digits is %d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `unsigned long long sum,value,rem;`

Comment: Why are you unsure if this is C or C++?

Comment: Try reading a string. That can be as long as you want.

Answer (score 5):

`9999999999` is too big a value to be held by `int`.

Referrence: `C11` standard, chapter §5.2.4.2.1,

```
INT_MAX                 +32767
UINT_MAX                 65535
LONG_MAX                +2147483647
ULONG_MAX                4294967295
LLONG_MAX               +9223372036854775807
ULLONG_MAX               18446744073709551615
```

Try using *bigger* data type, e.g., `long long int` or `unsigned long long int`. You should use appropriate conversion specifier for used data type.

As a note, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "INT_MAX = %d\n", INT_MAX );
    printf( "LLONG_MAX = %lld\n", LLONG_MAX );

    return 0;
}
```

when you will see the output similar to the following

```
INT_MAX = 2147483647
LLONG_MAX = 9223372036854775807
```

Thus value `9999999999` can not be stored in an object of type `int` because it is greater than `INT_MAX`.
Therefore define variable value like

```
long long int value;
```

or even it would be better to define it like

```
unsigned long long int value;
```

because your input does not expect negative values. In this case you have to use format specifier `%llu`. For example

```
scanf( "%llu", &value );
```

Also this code sniipet

```
while((value/10)>0)
{
    rem=value%10;
    sum=sum+rem;
    value=value/10;
}
sum=sum+value;
```

you could substitute for the following more simple and logically more consistent code snippet

```
do
{
    sum += value % 10;
} while ( value /= 10 );
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 1):

you are using

```
int sum,value,rem;
```

to declare integer variables. The variable `sum` holds the final answer of addition. change your variable type to `long int` or `double`. It Should look like

```
int value,rem;
long int sum
```

or

```
int value,rem;
double sum;
```

since the data type `int` cannot hold your 10 digit number so it causes an overflow.Using `double` or `long int` might fix your problem.